# Appended parameters to POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, axios

I am trying to submit remote form from my React component. The backend is made using Ruby on Rails.

```
<form
    className="message_form style__brook flex__column cen-hor cen-ver"
    id="new_message"
    acceptCharset="UTF-8"
    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
>
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"/>
    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="message[name]" id="message_name"/>
    <input placeholder="Mail" type="email" name="message[email]" id="message_email"/>
    <input placeholder="USD" type="number" name="message[budget]" id="message_budget"/>
    <input value="Evaluation" type="hidden" name="message[subject]" id="message_subject"/>
    <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message[body]" id="message_body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send" disabled="disabled" data-disable-with="Send"/>
</form>
```

and **handleSubmit** looks like this:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const object = getObjectFromForm();
    axios.post('/send_message', object)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

`getObjectFromForm` is a function where I get create an object so I can add it as parameters. `object` looks like this:

```
object = {utf: "...", message: {"name": ..., "email": ... etc.}}
```

When I add the `object` to axios POST function, it gets passed with the request, but there is another object appended to my parameters that key is `email` and it contains `object`'s keys and values. When I remove the `object` from axios method then no parameters are passed.

My qestion is - why is this second `email` object passed when I did not define it?

Comment: show a whole code of `getObjectFromForm`

Comment: Please post your getObjectFromForm method logic so we can see what it's doing, and also post actual json data dumps of the response - e.g. copy/paste the output of `console.log(getObjectFromForm());`.

Comment: The object value is as I wrote it to you. The thing is even when I repleace the object with some hand-written object, that contains only the keys and values I need there is still the other object appended as `email`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probabl with axios itself. Changing the code to use jQuery ajax method solves the problem.